# How to pass values through an AngularJS directive to a function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive with an attribute like this in my app.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:searchTerm | limitTo:limit ">
    <td>
        <span eachpost="{{post.id}}" id="{{post.id}}"></span>
           …
            other html 
            …
    </td>
</tr>
```

and angular.js file:

```
App.directive ("eachpost", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope:{
            id:"@"
        },
        templateUrl: '_eachpost.html',
    }
});
```

The directive works ok and passes and I can use {{id}} inside '_eachpost.html', but I'm trying to also kickstart a function which should use the value of 'id'.  I believe it's the link property but not sure how to include it in the directive.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
App.directive ("eachpost", function () {
return {
 restrict: "A",
 scope:{
 id:"@"
 },
 templateUrl: '_eachpost.html',
 link: function(scope, element, attrs){

     scope.$watch("id", function(newValue){
     } );

 }
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  If I'm reading right, I don't even need the part after the equals sign in my html…eachpost="{{post.id}}"?

Comment: I tested with an alert(newValue) and it occurs that my hg-repeat seems to be going through exactly twice. Any idea why?

Comment: About your first comment - yes, you don't need it, but I think you might want to change it to "post-id" or something, about the second one, create a Plunkr, and post it on a different question, 'cause it's hard to figure out from a static example.